# <layer-list> not looking same on different screen densities

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, shapes

I am applying my own background on edittext to achieve same solid color of underline without changing it's thickness on focus.

Next to my xml file I can see in brackets it's specified as xhdpi (see image attached)
When i run it on different density device the underline doesn't look perfect.

Is it because the xml file is specified as xhdpi? What does it mean? How to make it scale perfectly on all densities?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="1px"
                android:color="@color/purple" />

            <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please read [Android Developers: Support different pixel densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp)

## 1. Use one resource for all densities

Select the file and press **F6** (move file)

#### Then delete `-xhdpi` from the `To directory` field and click on OK

[image]

---

## 2. Create resource for each screen density

You will need to create other XML files with that same name and place them in the appropriate folder while modifying `android:width` and maybe padding to suit your taste
[image]
[image]

Comment: it did the trick with the brackets, but has nothing to do with underline thickness looking different though. thanks

Comment: This is the solution but you should explain why. What does F6 do? What si refactoring in this case? Why the drawable is inside `drawable-xhdpi`? Are there any other similar folders? Why is that important? Also remember, plenty of people use F keys as default (volume, brigth, etc), so OP could need fn + F6